# Stop query string from being appended to URL

Tags: .htaccess

I have a rewrite rule for my site that passes everything after the domain name as a parameter:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_=/&\-]+)?$ index.php?page=$1   [L,QSA]
```

But when going to:

```
mydomain.co.uk/mypage
```

..it is appending the query string after the URL (In the browser address bar) like this:

```
mydomain.co.uk/mypage?page=mypage
```

I thought it was just Chrome being weird... but it does it in IE aswell.

Has anyone ever had this? Any help would be great I just need it not to append the query string to the end and stay as "mydomain.co.uk/mypage"

Comment: You're using codeigniter right? Because I don't think that rewrite rule does what you think it does.

Comment: Nope, this is my own thing. Everything works perfectly, and doesn't break because of this problem. I just would like it to not push the query string to the URL so I can keep the URL pretty

Comment: My understainding is that the rewrite rule takes the URL `mysite.com/my_wonderful_page` and passes it to the server as `mysite.com/index.php?page=my_wonderful_page`. Right?

Comment: Yep, that is working I can get the page passed with $_GET["page"].. but for some reason in my case it's actually changing the URL in the browser address bar by putting ?page=something at the end

Comment: This is similar to what Codeigniter does. Here's something you could try based on their solution: ```RewriteEngine on       
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)      
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]```

Comment: I've tried that but unfortunately get the same issue :(

Comment: Make sure you have `RewriteEngine on` otherwise it won't work.
Also, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936716/htaccess-url-rewriting-challenge?rq=1

Comment: What are you other .htaccess rules? That 1 line can't be the only thing in your .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a condition to check if the requested file exists.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?page=$1   [L,QSA]
```

I tested this code with [htaccess.mwl.be](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) for this requested url `http://mydomain.co.uk/mypage?page=mypage` and it redirects to `http://mydomain.co.uk/index.php?page=mypage`